# mlab.specgram doesn't match pyplot.specgram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, fft

**SOLVED** ! Add **NFFT=4096** as a parameter in the mlab.specgram function!

I want to create spectrograms from an audio file. I did that using pylot.specgram. Looks wonderful. However, I don't want python to generate a figure after each specgram call. I just want to get the array to create a figure later on.

So I found mlab.specgram, which only creates the array, perfect. However, the plot looks really bad, not sharp, as if data has been averaged.

**Code for pyplot.specgram:**

```
file_path="wav1.wav"

samples, sampling_rate=librosa.load(file_path, sr= None, mono=True, offset=0.0, duration=None)
audio=samples

Pxx, freqs, time_bins, img = plt.specgram(audio, NFFT=4096, Fs=sampling_rate, mode='psd', noverlap=0, scale='dB', cmap="rainbow")

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlim([0, 120])
ax.set_ylim([800, 1200])
```

And it looks like this:
[image]

**Code for mlab.specgram:**

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53385242/matplotlib-spectrogram-animation-without-calling-pyplot-specgram-directly-every

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import librosa

FILENAME = 'wav1.wav'

NFFT = 4096
NOVERLAP = 0

sound, rate = librosa.load(FILENAME, sr= None, mono=True, offset=0.0, duration=None)

pad_xextent = (NFFT - NOVERLAP) / rate / 2

def create_specgram(sound_bit, rate):
    spec, freqs, t = plt.mlab.specgram(sound_bit, Fs=rate, NFFT=NFFT)
    
    xmin = np.min(t) - pad_xextent
    xmax = np.max(t) + pad_xextent
    extent = xmin, xmax, freqs[0], freqs[-1]
    arr = np.flipud(10. * np.log10(spec))
    return arr, extent


# calculate spectro
arr, extent = create_specgram( sound, rate)

# create image and plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
image = plt.imshow(arr, extent=extent, aspect='auto', cmap="rainbow")

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlim([0, 120])
ax.set_ylim([800, 1200])
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

I don't understand what's happening. What can I do ?

Comment: Solved. Need to add NFFT=4096 as a parameter in the function mlab.specgram()